# Regular safety properties and bad prefixes of $\omega$-regular properties

Tags: model-checking, program-verification, temporal-logic, omega-language

I have two questions:

By starting with a nondeterministic Büchi automaton (NBA) $\mathcal{A}^{\varphi} = (Q, \Sigma, \rightarrow, I, F )$ for an $\omega$-regular property $\varphi$, we can construct a NFA $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{\varphi} = (Q^{\prime}, \Sigma, \rightarrow^{\prime}, I^{\prime}, F^{\prime} )$ that recognizes the bad prefixes of $\varphi$ as the ***complement*** of NFA $\overline{\mathcal{A}}^{\varphi} = (Q, \Sigma, \rightarrow, I, F_1 )$:

For every state $q \in Q$, if there ***is*** a nontrivial strongly connected component (SCC) $C \subseteq Q$ such that  $C \cap F \neq \emptyset$ and $C$ is reachable from $q$, then $F_1 \leftarrow F_1 \cup \{q\}$. Basically, $q$ is in $F_1$ iff the language of $\mathcal{A}^{\varphi}$ starting from $q$ is nonempty.

**N.B.** A SCC consisting of a single state with a self-loop is considered nontrivial SCC.

> Does NFA $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{\varphi}$ recognize *all* bad prefixes of $\varphi$ and, hence, $\omega$-regular **safety** properties are regular **safety** properties, where a safety property is *regular* if its set of bad prefixes is a regular language?

By determinizing and complementing $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{\varphi}$, we can get a NBA $\mathcal{B}^{\psi}$.

> Is $\psi = Closure(\varphi)$?

According to [PMC](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/principles-model-checking), $Closure(\varphi)$ of a linear-time property $\varphi \subseteq \Sigma^{\omega}$ is the set of all infinite words whose finite prefixes are also prefixes of $\varphi$. This coincides with the notion of closure from topology, and $Closure(\varphi)$ will always be a safety property.

Sorry for the elementary question.

Comment: Could you define $Closure(\varphi)$?

Comment: @Shaull: I added the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction for bad prefixes is not correct on NBA's. 
For instance take the NBA on alphabet $A=\{a,b\}$ with two initial states $q_a$ and $q_b$ where for both $x\in A$, $q_x$ goes to an accepting sink if the first letter is $x$ and to a rejecting sink if the first letter is not $x$.

Then the language recognized is $A^\omega$, but the set of "bad prefixes" you compute is $A^*$ i.e. all finite words.

Your construction works if you first determinize the automaton. Then the new final states are the ones which cannot reach a component $C$ accepting some infinite word. Careful though, the deterministic automaton is no longer Büchi, it is a parity automaton, so it is a little more complicated to check if a component has empty language.

As for your question about closure, you are essentially asking if for any regular language $L$, $Closure(L)$ is the set of words containing no bad prefixes of $L$. This is true: a word is in the closure of $L$ iff it is arbitrarily close to words in $L$ iff it does not contain a bad prefix.

Comment: Denis. Thanks for your answer. Indeed, the construction was incorrect. I fixed it now, so please let me know if it implies any relationship between regular and $\omega$-regular **safety** properties. If not, and you know of a settling answer to that question, please point me to any relevant literature on this.

Comment: With the new definitions the answers are all yes, but it is really not research-level and should rather be on cs.stackexchange.